# Autocompletion for Emacs in my-sql mode

Tags: mysql, emacs, autocomplete

I would like to know if there is a auto-complete feature in emacs for my-sql. I tried using the sql-completion.el from [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlCompletion), and when I use it emacs gives the following error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: <!DOCTYPE
```

How do I fix this or is there any other auto-completing function for emacs in my-sql mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will guess that the sql-completion.el file you downloaded somehow had HTML formatting.  Open the file inside emacs, and if it starts with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC...`, there you have your problem.

Comment: Thanks Leo. I do not know how I missed it. You were right the file had the html tags all over the place.